# Spectrum of the Laplacian on p-forms on the sphere

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=AUCN&pg7=MR&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=gallot&s5=&s6=meyer&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=454884) the authors give an explicit description of the eigenforms and spectrum of the Laplacian acting on $p$-forms on the round sphere $S^n$, apparently citing an unpublished computation of Calabi.

Although the AMS reviewer says that there is a "minor typographical errors" in such computation.

Can you help me to find the errors or suggest me a correct reference for the laplacian on p-forms on the round sphere, possibly more explicit than Ikeda and Taniguchi's 1978 paper?

Thanks

David

Comment: Ref: Berger, Gauduchon, Mazet, Le Spectre d'un variete Riemannienne

Comment: I think it's perfect for the laplacian on functions but they don't say much about the one on forms

Comment: Good point. The other, more relevant, reference that I forgot to mention is Folland, *Harmonic Analysis of the de Rham complex of the sphere*, Crelles 1989

Answer (score 8):

I like the following description of the spectrum of $S^{2m-1}$ via representation theory of $SO(2m)$. 
Assume $n=2m-1$. 
Let $\mathcal E_0=\{0\}$ and $$\mathcal E_p=\{\lambda_{k,p}:=k^2+k(2m-2)+(p-1)(2m-1-p): k\in \mathbb N\},$$ for $1\leq p\leq m$. 
One can check that $\mathcal E_p\cap\mathcal E_{p+1}$ is empty for every $0\leq p\leq m-1$.

The eigenvalues of the Hodge-Laplace operator $\Delta_p$ on $p$ forms on $S^{2m-1}$ are $\mathcal E_p\cup\mathcal E_{p+1}$ for $0\leq p\leq m-1$. 
The multiplicity is given by 
$$
\textrm{mult}(\lambda) = 
\begin{cases}
\dim \pi_{k,p} & \text{ if } \lambda=\lambda_{k,p},\\
\dim \pi_{k,p+1} & \text{ if } \lambda=\lambda_{k,p+1}.
\end{cases}
$$

Here, $\pi_{k,p}$ denotes the irreducible representation of $SO(2m)$ having highest weight $(k\varepsilon_1+\dots+\varepsilon_p)$ when $1\leq p\leq m-1$, and $\pi_{k,m}$ denotes the sum of the irreducible representations with highest weight $(k\varepsilon_1+\dots+\varepsilon_m)$ and $(k\varepsilon_1+\dots+\varepsilon_{m-1}-\varepsilon_m)$ respectively.

You can compute $\dim \pi_{k,p}$ by using Weyl's dimension formula.

Comment: Did you do this by seeing in Ikeda-Taniguchi which irreps of SO(2m) appear in $C^\infty(\Lambda^p (S^{2m-1}))$ and seeing which engenvalue the Casimir has on them? If so I think it should be $\lambda_{k,p} = (k+p)(k+2m-p)$.

Comment: I corrected the highest weights of $\pi_{k,p}$. I hope now this coincides with Ikeda-Taniguchi's work.